# Mousewheel scrolling not working in my website

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-ui

I added some scripts last night to my website and suddenly I lost chance to scroll the web page which mousewheel. It works fine if I drag the side but not working when I swipe down on my Mac trackpad.

Link: http://www.mallaprojects.com/mt

to paste the code I am not even sure where the issue is :(

Can anyone help me fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: For one thing, that slider is capturing all keydown and scroll events, turning them to animation.

Comment: The line which prevents the scroll is in the file /js/dasky.eval.js line no. 99, with the code `return b = a.event.fix(c)...`. I commented out that code and the scroll worked for me. Hope this helps you in debugging.

Comment: @Chirag64 - thanks mate, it's working. I can mark it as right answer if you post the same as answer.

Comment: Posted the same as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line which prevents the scroll is in the file `/js/dasky.eval.js` line no. 99, with the code `return b = a.event.fix(c)...`. I commented out that code and the scroll worked for me.

However, the scrolling action will no longer work on the slider, so you might have to dig into the code if you want to enable scrolling without breaking that functionality.

Hope this helps you in debugging.